# Slick slider not working properly in bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, slider

I think i have done everything right according to slick slider official website, yet once im done setting everything up the slider doesnt work, it just shows the images one on top of the other.

Here's my code:

Head elements

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css"/>
```

Body elements

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="autoplay">
        <div><img src=".\slickpics\cookie1.png"></div>
        <div><img src=".\slickpics\cookie1.png"></div>
        <div><img src=".\slickpics\cookie1.png"></div>
        <div><img src=".\slickpics\cookie1.png"></div>
        <div><img src=".\slickpics\cookie1.png"></div>
        <div><img src=".\slickpics\cookie1.png"></div>
        <div><img src=".\slickpics\cookie1.png"></div>
        <div><img src=".\slickpics\cookie1.png"></div>
        <div><img src=".\slickpics\cookie1.png"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Before body closing elements

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.1.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-ycJeXbll9m7dHKeaPbXBkZH8BuP99SmPm/8q5O+SbBc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```

The javascript at the end

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.autoplay').slick({
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      infinite: true,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    });
});
```

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated and thanks for your time.

Comment: You're loading an outdated version of jQuery. Slick requires jQuery version `3.0` or higher. You're loading `1.12`. Try using a more up-to-date version of jQuery and see if that solves your issue. Something like `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`. You also most likely don't need jQuery migrate... so I'd probably remove that as well.

Comment: Updated but still not working.

Comment: The next thing I would check is your folder structure. Do the Slick files actually exist where you're referencing them? Note that `/slick/slick.min.js` and `slick/slick.min.js` are not the same thing. A basic implementation of your code works for me [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2d967ah8/). So I would double check the paths your using.

Comment: i raplaced all references for the ones in your fiddle example and its still not working, this is driving me crazy.

Comment: No worries, It's probably something simple that you're missing. The code you posted in your question works (when I swap the links). So, that might indicate that you're problem is elsewhere. Do you see any errors in the browser console when you load the page?

Comment: Yes actually, i put them in the pastebin link since there are too many characters for a comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/PkbHjPkF

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208516/discussion-between-volt-and-minnen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery CND was repeated, there was one for bootstrap and one for slickslider, i solved this issue by removing one of them, specifically the one from slickslider.